# I want the street name and address with logitute and latitude as shown in image in android

Tags: android, dictionary

I want the street  name and longitude latitude of entered pin code in edit text as shown in the image of google map. I want to develop this type of feature in android.
Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: Use Google Places API.

Comment: What @AmanTonk said coupled with [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
        Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> add;
try {

    add = geo.getFromLocation(taplat, taplon, 1);
    addstr = add.get(0).getPostalCode();

}
```